# How to pass options to doparallel workers?

Tags: r, doparallel

I use options() and getOption() to set options for how my code executes. In sequential operation it works fine.

But when I use the doparallel package to run my code in parallel, the options don't get passed to the worker processes. Sample code that shows the problem:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
registerDoParallel()

options(a=1)
getOption('a')
## [1] 1

foreach(id=1) %dopar% getOption('a')
## [[1]] 
## NULL
```

As you can see, the options vector isn't passed to the parallel worker. I tried exporting `.Options` in `foreach`, but I get the same result:

```
foreach(id=1, .export=c('.Options')) %dopar% getOption('a')
## [[1]] 
## NULL
```

So this is breaking my code in parallel processing.

Is this a known problem? I've searched around for it and haven't found anything. How can I make doparallel pass the options vector to its workers?

Answer (score 0):

One answer is to set them manually in each %dopar% call:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
registerDoParallel()

options(a=1)
opt <- options()
foreach (n=1) %dopar% {
  options(opt)
  getOption('a')
}
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
```

I was hoping that %dopar% would take care of this itself, but this answer does work.